# Are cabin temperatures related to destination weather?

Tags: commercial-aviation, temperature

I've been in a long-distance flight between northern and southern hemisphere, with temperatures nearing 5°C on the origin, and 25°C on the destination.

During the first flight, the cabin was excessively hot; one *possible* explanation would be that the sun was shining on my side of the cabin, and the new "no-blinds" system, even when darkened to block most of the light, was still unable to contain the heat.

However, on the return flight (from hot area to cold area), the sun was *also* shining on my side of the cabin, yet it was much colder (note: I was wearing exactly the same clothes in both flights), as if the cabin temperature had been deliberately set, in both flights, to match the weather at arrival.

I couldn't find any information about this policy. Is it just coincidence? Are companies supposed to follow some set of rules to e.g. minimize temperature shock when arriving?

**Edit**: The aircraft was a Dreamliner.

Comment: Do you remember the airplane's model?

Comment: When you come out of a 5°C environment, a 20°C environment feels warm. When you come out of a 25°C environment, the same 20°C environment feels cold. Not saying that this was the case here, but it could play a role.

Comment: @sophit : a Dreamliner, I just added it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There are no global rules of this nature.

However, some airlines set their own rules, usually setting the upper limit at 29-32 °C and the lower around 18-20 °C. Some pilots will clearly have preferences for warmer or cooler temperature.

But this is only incidentally related to the destination - you're more likely to be flown to Scandinavia by a Scandinavian pilot, and to Africa by an African pilot on an African airline than vice versa. More likely, not a rule.

Most passengers will spend at least an hour at the airport after disembarking, and airport indoor temperatures vary only slightly around the world.

Comment: Yikes! Having a cabin temp of 29-32°C (84-89°F) would be _miserable_ even for a short flight! I'd sleep well, though - that kind of heat and stuffy environment would put me right out...

Comment: @FreeMan [Not a joke](https://www.tourism-review.com/us-airlines-to-set-cabin-temperature-limits-news13707). Most pilots will target 80F or less, but they will fly with a hotter cabin if it doesn't work out.

Comment: Ugh... Never taken a thermometer aboard with me, but I'm pretty sure I've been in some hot cabins. Probably never quite _that_ hot, though. Once the engines spin up and the PACS are fired up, temp usually comes right down.